# Collision detection and image identification issue

Tags: vb.net

I have another problem on regarding collision detection. I'm currently using pictureboxes to make falling objects in which these pictureboxes' images are fetched in a random manner from an imagelist I also created. The problem is, there are 2 types of images; a fish and a coin. What I want to do is to make the program recognize the image(if its a coin or not) a certain collision had and update a label in which the coin procedure is binded. I've tried various things but I can't seem to figure out the source of the problem. Can anyone please help me out?

I have this code so far:

```
'Collision
    If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
        If PictureBox1.ImageLocation Is My.Resources.coin Then
            cns += 1
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If
        PictureBox1.Top -= Panel1.Height
        PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno1)
        scr += 1
        lbl_score.Text += scr
    End If
    If PictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
        If PictureBox1.ImageLocation Is My.Resources.coin Then
            cns += 1
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If
        PictureBox2.Top -= Panel1.Height
        PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox2.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno2)
        scr += 1
        lbl_score.Text += scr
    End If
    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
        If PictureBox3.ImageLocation Is My.Resources.coin Then
            cns += 1
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If
        PictureBox3.Top -= Panel1.Height
        PictureBox3.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox3.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno3)
        scr += 1
        lbl_score.Text += scr
    End If
```

This is the list of images and its random function respectively:

```
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.coin)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f1)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f2)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f3)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f4)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f5)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f6)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f7)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f8)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(My.Resources.f9)


Dim cns As Integer = 0
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim rno1 As Integer
Dim rno2 As Integer
Dim rno3 As Integer

rno1 = rnd.Next(0, 10)
rno2 = rnd.Next(0, 10)
rno3 = rnd.Next(0, 10)
```

EDIT:

Here's the whole code.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class EClassic
Dim images() As String
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim rno1 As Integer
Dim rno2 As Integer
Dim rno3 As Integer
Dim flist As New List(Of PictureBox)
Dim dlist As New List(Of Image)
Dim scr As Integer = 0
Dim life As Integer = 5
Dim cns As Integer = 0
Dim picturebox1ImageIndex, picturebox2ImageIndex, picturebox3ImageIndex As Integer
Private Sub EClassic_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With flist
        .Add(PictureBox1)
        .Add(PictureBox2)
        .Add(PictureBox3)
    End With
    lbl_score.Text = scr
    lbl_life.Text = life
    lbl_coins.Text = cns

End Sub
Private Sub EClassic_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Dim c As Integer = Panel1.ClientSize.Width
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim res2 As Integer
    res2 = c - c + 100
    res = c / 2

    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left
            If play_avatar.Left > res2 Then
                play_avatar.Left -= 100
            ElseIf play_avatar.Left < res2 Then
                play_avatar.Left -= 0
            End If

        Case Keys.Right
            If play_avatar.Left < res Then
                play_avatar.Left += 100
            ElseIf play_avatar.Left > res Then
                play_avatar.Left -= 0

            End If

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim mov As Integer = rnd.Next(0, flist.Count - 0)
    Me.flist(mov).Top += 20
    'Fish - Dragon Collision
    If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
        PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Top -= Panel1.Height
        rno1 = rnd.Next(0, 9)
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno1)
        picturebox1ImageIndex = rno1
        scr += 1
        lbl_score.Text += scr
        If picturebox1ImageIndex = 0 Then '0 is the index of coin in ImageList1
            cns += 1
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If
    End If
    If PictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
        PictureBox2.Image.Dispose() 
        PictureBox2.Top -= Panel1.Height
        rno2 = rnd.Next(0, 9)
        PictureBox2.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno2)
        picturebox2ImageIndex = rno2
        scr += 1
        lbl_score.Text += scr
        If picturebox2ImageIndex = 0 Then 
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If
    End If

    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
        PictureBox3.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox3.Top -= Panel1.Height
        rno3 = rnd.Next(0, 9)
        PictureBox3.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno3)
        picturebox3ImageIndex = rno3
        scr += 1
        lbl_score.Text += scr
        If picturebox3ImageIndex = 0 Then
            cns += 1
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If
    End If

    'Fish - Line Collision
    If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(line.Bounds) Then
        life -= 1
        PictureBox1.Top -= Panel1.Height
        lbl_life.Text = life
    End If
    If PictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(line.Bounds) Then
        life -= 1
        PictureBox2.Top -= Panel1.Height
        lbl_life.Text = life
    End If
    If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(line.Bounds) Then
        life -= 1
        PictureBox3.Top -= Panel1.Height
        lbl_life.Text = life
    End If
    If life = 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        GameOver.Show()
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What is the actual problem? You've only stated what you want the code to do, not what it currently does.

Comment: I think the program does not recognize if it is a coin or not, all just equal(fishes). How can I possibly make the program recognize if it is a coin right after randomization? Or even not after randomization I think will do.. I'm totally lost. Probably here is the problem, no? `If PictureBox1.ImageLocation Is My.Resources.coin Then
            cns += 1
            lbl_coins.Text += cns
        End If`

Comment: Because after that condition, the cns(actually the coin counter) wasn't updating.

Answer (score 0):

*PictureBox1.ImageLocation Is My.Resources.coin* is wrong in two ways:

`1. comparing string with bitmap. Turn on option strict`
`2. even if you do PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.coin it will always be false because it is a different object`

You should use a variable for each picturebox eg picturebox1ImageIndex, picturebox2ImageIndex and compare

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
Dim mov As Integer = rnd.Next(0, flist.Count - 0)
Me.flist(mov).Top += 20
'Fish - Dragon Collision
If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
    'PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()   ' you dont need that
    PictureBox1.Top -= Panel1.Height '<- place break point. See if this code is triggered
    rno1 = rnd.Next(0, 9)
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno1) '<- place break point check rno1 
    picturebox1ImageIndex = rno1
    scr += 1 '<- place break point check picturebox1ImageIndex 
    lbl_score.Text += scr
    If picturebox1ImageIndex = 0 Then '<- place break point
        cns += 1 '<- place break point
        lbl_coins.Text += cns
    End If
End If
If PictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
    'PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()   ' you dont need that
    PictureBox2.Top -= Panel1.Height '<- place break point. See if this code is triggered
    rno2 = rnd.Next(0, 9)
    PictureBox2.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno2) '<- place break point check rno2
    picturebox2ImageIndex = rno2
    scr += 1 '<- place break point check picturebox2ImageIndex 
    lbl_score.Text += scr
    If picturebox2ImageIndex = 0 Then  '<- place break point
        lbl_coins.Text += cns '<- place break point
    End If
End If

If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then
    'PictureBox3.Image.Dispose() ' you dont need that
    PictureBox3.Top -= Panel1.Height '<- place break point. See if this code is triggered
    rno3 = rnd.Next(0, 9)
    PictureBox3.Image = ImageList1.Images(rno3) '<- place break point check rno3
    picturebox3ImageIndex = rno3
    scr += 1 '<- place break point check picturebox3ImageIndex
    lbl_score.Text += scr
    If picturebox3ImageIndex = 0 Then '<- place break point
        cns += 1 '<- place break point
        lbl_coins.Text += cns
    End If
End If

'Fish - Line Collision
If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(line.Bounds) Then
    life -= 1
    PictureBox1.Top -= Panel1.Height
    lbl_life.Text = life
End If
If PictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(line.Bounds) Then
    life -= 1
    PictureBox2.Top -= Panel1.Height
    lbl_life.Text = life
End If
If PictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(line.Bounds) Then
    life -= 1
    PictureBox3.Top -= Panel1.Height
    lbl_life.Text = life
End If
If life = 0 Then
    Timer1.Stop()
    GameOver.Show()
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share some ideas to fix it? I can't seem to find a way, sorry.

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε
Thank you for that one. Though it seems that there is a little problem. Please see EDIT:

Comment: @Chris So you are saying that rno1 gets the random value and then changes again? I dont understand.

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε
Correct me if I'm wrong but this is what I think.
Please check EDIT:

Comment: Or maybe the rno2 is the problem. Maybe if I call rno2 in different places to be assigned, it generates another random value everytime I call it. I'm very sorry, I'm totally lost here. Thanks for your ideas though.

Comment: @Chris First of all you dont have to dispose the image. *PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()* is not needed. Second, rno2 from the moment it gets the random value doesnt change, the same goes to *picturebox2ImageIndex*. They are just integers. Use break points to see the values. Do you have a timer that is changing rno2 value?

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε
I posted the whole code in the timer_tick event in EDIT.

Comment: @Chris I cant find anything wrong in timer. Can you post a link of your entire code?

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε
Please see EDIT.

Comment: @Chris What is *play_avatar* and *line*?

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε It's the object that I'm moving using keys left and right in which a collision is subjected for earning scores and coins. The line on the other hand is the pitfall or just a dead end. If falling objects(pictureboxes) hit the line, lives are decremented.

Comment: @Chris I cant find anything wrong with the code. What is the problem you experience exactly?

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε
The problem is that falling objects(pictureboxes with coin image) doesn't seem to trigger the coin counter, but sometimes it would, alongside with other images(random f1,f2,coin,f3,...). In other words, coin accumulation is also in a random manner and I don't know why.

Comment: @Chris The coin counter isn't triggered not because the random variable `rno1, rno2, rno3` change after it is been assigned a value, but because your code is wrong in triggering. It is the easiest thing to check. Place break points to see if the code runs as expected. I am guessing but i dont think you get inside the *If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(play_avatar.Bounds) Then*. See edit